# What is the relationship between dimension of eigen space and multiplity of eigen value?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is there a relationship between dimension of eigen space with respect to an eigen value $\lambda_i$ and multiplicity of eigen value $\lambda_i$ ( by multiplicity I mean if $(\lambda-2 )^3(\lambda -1)^2 = 0$ is the eigen value equation then multiplicity for eigen value 2 is 3 and for 1 is 2 )  for a general square matrix ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the dimension of the eigenspace is always less or equal than the multiplicity in the characteristic polynomial. 
(If there is a nontrivial Jordan block for the eigenvalue $\lambda_i$, then it is strictly less.)

Comment: could you give a hint on how to prove it ?

Comment: **Hint:** Jordan normal form.

Answer (score 3):

The eigenspace dimension corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda$ is called the *geometric multiplicity* of $\lambda$, while the multiplicity of $\lambda$ as a root of the characteristic polynomial is called the *algebraic multiplicity*.  The two are [related](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Algebraic_multiplicity) as $$1\le gm(\lambda)\le am(\lambda)$$
for each eigenvalue $\lambda$.